# Pygame Sprite flickers when moving

Tags: python, animation, pygame, sprite

I am new to pygame and have been having some problems with a sprite flickering/dragging it's image when it moves across the screen. I have read other answers on here about getting a certain pix/s, where you should change the framerate and lower pix/frame, but that solution hasn't helped so I was wondering if I'm just not implementing it correctly and that's the only solution or if I am missing something. Below is some the code for the game that runs at a constant framerate. Thank you!

```
pygame.init()
display=pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height), pygame.RESIZABLE)
background=pygame.Surface((screen_width, screen_height))
background.fill(background_color)

class Ship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.original_image_unscaled=pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.original_image=pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.original_image_unscaled, (56,70))
        self.image=self.original_image
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.xpos=0
        self.ypos=0
        self.rect.centerx=self.xpos
        self.rect.centery=self.ypos
        self.vel=0
        self.acc=.05
        self.brake=.2
        self.turn_brake=1.5
        self.angle=0
        self.max_speed=5

    def getShipPos(self):
        return (self.xpos, self.ypos)

    def getShipVel(self):
        return self.vel

    def getShipAcc(self):
        return self.acc

    def getShipRect(self):
        return self.rect

    def update(self):
        self.rect.centerx=self.xpos
        self.rect.centery=self.ypos

    def rotateShip(self, angle):
        #this rotates the ship by a specified angle
        self.image, self.rect = pygameRotateImage2(self.original_image, self.rect, angle-self.angle)
        self.angle+=angle

    def simpleMove(self, x_final, y_final):
        self.xpos=x_final
        self.ypos=y_final

    def moveShip(self):
        keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        xpos_i=self.xpos
        ypos_i=self.ypos
        if keys[K_w]:
            if self.vel>self.max_speed:
                self.vel=self.max_speed
            else:
                self.vel+=self.acc          
        elif keys[K_s]:
            self.vel-=self.brake
            if self.vel<0:
                self.vel=0          

        if keys[K_a]:
            self.rotateShip(-self.turn_brake)
        elif keys[K_d]:
            self.rotateShip(self.turn_brake)

        self.xpos+=self.vel*math.sin(math.radians(self.angle))
        self.ypos+= -self.vel*math.cos(math.radians(self.angle))

display.blit(background, (0,0))
pygame.display.update()

player_ship=Ship('image.png')
player_ship.simpleMove(screen_width/2, screen_height/2)

movement_group=pygame.sprite.Group()
movement_group.add(player_ship)

clock=pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    (mousex,mousey)=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    player_ship.moveShip()

    movement_group.update()
    display.blit(background, (0,0))
    movement_group.draw(display)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: At first glance, nothing seems wrong with it. I tried running your code but got many errors. Is this your complete code?

Comment: No, it's not, I took out the import pygame, math line and the rotation function which is just a general one that I took from the pygame website. Also screen width, height and background color need to be implemented, I left those variable so people could choose what they wanted on their screen.

Answer (score 0):

Double buffering will probably help at least some. It is a technique used in computer graphics to reduce the number of times a pixel changes. It can be implemented as:

```
pygame.display.set_mode(dimensions, pygame.RESIZEABLE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
```

Another option is to move the `clock.tick` from the beginning of the loop to the end of the loop. That is where I usually see it, and it could alter the outcome of the graphics.

Comment: That didn't seem to do much unfortunately. Maybe pygame isn't what I should be using? I find that hard to believe though because this seems like such a simple thing to do, it's just moving an object around on a screen. Even when I take out the rotation portion I still don't get a nice image moving across a screen. Maybe I'm asking for too much?

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick replies! Unfortunately I have tried that too. I have also tried: having two clock.tick() statements, increasing the FPS on the clock.tick() statements, changing pygame.display.update() to pygame.display.flip(), not using sprites at all and just blitting the image to the rectangle each time,

Comment: I have tried only updating the player_ship.rect in the pygame.display.update(), and changing the ship to just a white square and they have all still led to dragging/flickering. In comparison for what I'm looking for I have looked at some scripts and watched the videos from [link](http://physics.gac.edu/~miller/jterm_2013/physics_engine_tutorial.html). These videos have many moving objects that are smoothly moving (especially the color bars example) and yet when I look at the code I cannot see what is different

Comment: Also I'll mention that I am using a Linux machine running Elementary OS in case that could be an issue as well

Comment: Yeah I think this is just what pygame does, I looked at the racing game GRIP on the pygame website and if you watch closely the background stutters like every second and the red/white strips on the side blur a little when you go fast, I understand blurring is going to happen with a moving object, it just seems a like too much.

Comment: This is my first time dealing with any kind of 'animation' though so this could be completely normal and I just haven't noticed it in other games

Comment: @TTrickle I don't really have much experience in making pygame games. I have never had this problem before.

Comment: @TTrickle Have you tried defining `xpos` and `ypos` as floats? I think they are getting coerced into floats anyway, so it probably doesn't matter. --- Your rect update can use `Rect`s `.center` property like: `self.rect.center = self.xpos, self.ypos` . ---  Another  test is try the same basic program using `pySFML` or `pySDL2` to see if that improves, because they use hardware acceleration by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line `pygame.display.update()` to `pygame.display.flip()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the past.
I now usually create a method in the classes that need to be displayed on screen which blit the picture (of the class itself) to the screen.
I than call that method before the screen update.

For example, this is a method of the class "Tank", which actually build the tank used by the player:

```
def master_player(self): #calculate and draw the player sprite
    self.posix() # call of a method which calculate the position
    self.image_tank.set_colorkey(PURPLE)
    screen.blit(player.image_tank, player.position_tuple)
```

As I said before, I call this method at the end of the game loop and before the screen update.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the ***player_ship.moveShip()*** right under the ***pygame.display.update()***

Like this:
    player_ship.moveShip()

```
movement_group.update()
display.blit(background, (0,0))
movement_group.draw(display)
pygame.display.update()
```